# How much ram can you use on a 64 bit cpu running 32 bit os?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, 32bit-64bit, ram

Beginner here.

cpu says > 4GB, OS tells <4GB.

What is the answer?

Comment: 32 bit OS can't allocate more than 4Gb RAM

Comment: In fact, a 32-bit OS can't _address_ more than 4GB of RAM.

Comment: On Windows not even more than 3GB per application. By the way - what does Google say?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Super User: Can a 32-bit OS machine use up all 8GB RAM + 20GB page file?](http://superuser.com/questions/367490/can-a-32-bit-os-machine-use-up-all-8gb-ram-20gb-page-file)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I saw in windows, it is 2.8GB, in linux i think it can access complete 4GB

Comment: A reference for that would be nice ;-)

Comment: For Windows the relevant reference seems to be [MSDN: Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx) and it does not quite support the "_I saw...2.8GB_"